# Создание веб приложений. Сокеты

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, web-apps

Подскажите пожалуйста, откуда можно начать изучение создания веб приложений и сокетов? Откуда вы сами изучали и как? Посоветуйте книги для изучения созданий веб приложений с **нуля**. Я весь инет обыскал, но не смог найти чего то для новичков и чтобы было с объяснением.

Comment: Честно не знаю, есть ли там про сокеты. Но по шарпу могу посоветывать книгу Эндрю Троелсена.

Answer (score 3):

[Делаем чат на ASP.NET с помощью Web Socket](http://habrahabr.ru/post/145077/)

[Асинхронная работа с сокетами в C#. Сервер](http://cyber-blog.klan-hub.ru/2010/08/28/%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-c-%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BF/)

[Асинхронная работа с сокетами в C#. Клиент](http://cyber-blog.klan-hub.ru/2010/09/19/%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-c%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BF-%D0%BA/)

Comment: @Merlin а на основе ASP создают чаты, например facebook или twitter приложения??? Мне вот это интересно